# Is it possible to display views result counter as a field in a node?

Tags: views, display-suite

Using D7 and the latest DS and Views modules, is it possible to display the node position in a view (view result counter) inside the node full view display?
I'm ordering views items based on rating and I need to get every node's position in the view as a field in my nodes.
How can I achieve that?
thanks